# NiFi: port to use in handlehttprequest

Tags: apache-nifi

NiFi 1.5:

i want to use the port in HandleHTTPRequest. how to decide the port can be used in HandleHTTPRequest? is there any range of port can be used here.

i already saw the nifi configuration, but could not find the ports that can be used here.

please guide me. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Any port that the OS user running NiFi can access can be used for HandleHttpRequest, but only one can be used at a time (not a range). For example, sometimes the "NiFi user" (meaning the OS user that executed the `nifi.sh` command to start it) isn't allowed to use system ports (<1024) so you'd need to choose one above that number. Also you need to choose a port that is not already in use by another process.

The reason a port range is not available is because HandleHttpRequest is meant to model a well-known URL as a web service; if the ports could change, the clients would all have to try the same range.

Comment: thanks for your response. i am able to use the port within the range 6630 to 6650. how it can be configured for NiFi to use in this specific range?

Comment: You can only choose a single port from that range.

Comment: yes i understand. how NiFi knows to use only in the range? where can we check?

Comment: It will create a socket on the port you specify, so you need to specify a port within the range.